# Forming a distinct string from a Pair key in Java

Tags: java

I am new to coding and I am trying to solve this issue in Java.
I would like to form a string from the key Pairs such that I get "1234".
The left and right values of a key indicate which other pair should join it. The value score is considered the end and not really needed.
e.g. 3,4 would join with 2,3 to form 234. Then 1,2 would join with 234 to form 1234. Since the 4,1 has a low value, it is considered the end and not needed since we now have 1234.

I don't really know where to start with this and what I've tried does not yield what I need. I would much appreciate some help on this.

'''

```
LinkedHashMap<Pair<Integer, Integer>, Double> list = new LinkedHashMap<>();

list.put(new Pair<>(4, 1), 20.12);
list.put(new Pair<>(2, 3), 110.58);
list.put(new Pair<>(1, 2), 132.61);
list.put(new Pair<>(3, 4), 118.54);

StringBuilder s = new StringBuilder(); 

list.entrySet().stream(). 
sorted(Map.Entry.comparingByValue(Comparator.reverseOrder())).forEachOrdered(
             x ->     s.append(String.valueOf(x.getKey().getLeft()).concat(String.valueOf(x.getKey().getRight()))));


System.out.println(s.toString());
```

'''

Comment: Could you describe how the algorithm should work? First sort the data by `score` (= map value), then take the `Pair` (= map key) with the highest score, which would be `(1, 2)` in your example code. Then find the next `Pair` that can be joined? It's joinable when *"the first value of `previousPair` is equal to the second value of `nextPair`"* if I understood correctly. This would result in `nextPair = (4, 1)`. And when is the algorithm done? When no more matches can be found, or some other condition?

Comment: Sorry I am really bad at explaining it. I am trying to implement the following https://ciphertools.co.uk/InfoTranspositionPage2.php where it puts the key together.

Comment: C'mon. Give it a try. Reading several pages of an unknown topic is not easy. But I guess you know how it *should* work. Start with the 4 values you got in your example code, and then make a list, step by step, what should happen in which order. Where to start, where to stop.

Comment: @jaydee-187 "Sorry I am really bad at explaining it": work on improving that ability. It helps you to break down the problem into manageable chunks. If someone else can follow your explanation, you can be quite sure you didn't miss a step in your reasoning process. Sometimes, it even helps to explain your problem to a non-responsive rubber duck.